# How can I make row-click independent of checkbox-selection of row in react-tabulator?

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, tabulator, onrowclick

I wish to select a row on row click and select the checkbox on check. these should be independent of each other.

I tried making the row selectable as true in options, but want to change the "rowSelection" formatters settings as being independent

```
const options = {
      height: 270,
      width:  100,
      layout:"fitColumns",
      tooltips:true,
      rowSelected:true,
      autoResize:true
    };
```

```
columns= {[
            {formatter:"rowSelection", titleFormatter:"rowSelection", align:"center", headerSort:false, cellClick:function(e, cell){
                cell.getRow().toggleSelect();
                // cell._cell.setValue(true);
                console.log("CheckboxSelection......", cell)
              }, width: 20},
```

Comment: It's hard to understand what you're trying to achieve. What means "independed of each other"? What do you expect to happen to the row selection if your checkbox is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the ***rowSelection*** formatter you don't need to handle the ***cellClick*** event it should toggle the selection for you.

if you are trying to stop a ***cellClick*** propagating to a row click then you should call the ***stopPropagation*** function on the event in the ***cellClick***:

```js
cellClick:function(e, cell){
    e.stopPropagation(); // prevent click event propagating up to row.
}
```